# Linq chained SELECT and DISTINCT operators

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ and had a basic query.

Say I have a large List of Customer Objects

```
List<Customer> c = null;
c = //Fetch from DB - resulting into 1000+ non-unique Customers;
```

And if I convert the list into a List of say another class - for lack of a better name - CustomerEntity and then pick out the distinct ones as follows:

```
    var ce = c.Select(cust => new CustomerEntity() 
                     {
                         CustomerID = cust.CustID,
                         CustomerName = cust.CustName
                     }).Distinct(new CustomerEntityComparer()).ToList();
```

CustomerEntityComparer is just a class that compares 2 CustomerEntity objects on the basis of CustomerID.
My query is:
If Select and Distinct are chained, will that result in multiple iterations over the List?

Thanks

Vikas

Comment: What is the question? What have you done to investigate it?

Comment: Simple answer is: no. But you could do those transformations (`SELECT DISTINCT`) on the database side...

Comment: If you want to know more about the inner workings of LINQ (to objects) I recommend http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx where Jon Skeet reinvents LINQ and explains all the principles involved (such as when a list actually gets iterated over). The simple answer though is that it will only iterate the original list once.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Will check that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a more elaborate answer:
You can notice that Select() returns an IEnumerable, and so does Distinct(). That's because you're basically creating a query. No selection or distinct filtering is done until you call the ToList() method. When the ToList() method is executed, the whole query is evaluated. That's called Deferred Execution.

The advantage of this is that you can create queries like:

```
var ceQuery = c.Select(cust => new CustomerEntity() 
{
    CustomerID = cust.CustID,
    CustomerName = cust.CustName
}).Distinct(new CustomerEntityComparer());
```

and then every time the "c" has changed, you can just re-use the same ceQuery to get the latest restul:

```
var ce = ceQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I was aware that in case of LINQ To SQL the query gets converted into an expression tree and then when exec is requested - the tree is used to generate SQL. I also was aware of the Deferred execution aspect for L2Objects. But was not confident that in case of L2Objects the 2 chained calls will actually iterate only once over the collection, even with Deferred execution.My doubt was that it was left to the way, the SELECT & DISTINCT ops were implemented. Hence wanted to double check.